# Argument binding in closure function

Tags: python, function, arguments, closures

```
def test():
    x = 99
    def nested(x):
        print (x)
    return nested

a = test()
a()
```

**TypeError: nested() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'**

When I call `nested` to print argument x assigned in closure function `test`, the TypeError prompts me to pass a positional argument into nested, but why 'x' assigned in test function didn't be passed into nested?

Comment: But you *didn't* pass that into nested.

Comment: If you want to call your nested function without an argument, declare it as `def nested():`

Comment: when you code `def nested(x):` `x` is the name of a parameter, it's not refering to the `x` declared before

Comment: In your code, `a` is now a function that requires an argument (by the definition of `nested`). You have two options. Pass an argument to `a`, i.e. `a(99)` or redefine the function `nested` as `def nested: print(x)`

Comment: You should know that there is a feature in the Python standard library that does exactly what you are doing in your example. It's called a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and allows you to create proxy functions that call an original function with given arguments.

Answer (score 5):

```
def test():
    x = 99
    def nested():
        print (x)
    return nested

a = test()
a()
```

The function namespace is inherited automatically, you don’t have to pass it as an argument. If you include an argument into the function definition, then you have to obligatorily pass it a value when you call the function (unless you set a default value, for example:)

```
def test():
    x = 99
    def nested(y=100):
        print (x,y)
    return nested

a = test()
a() # will prinnt 99,100 because x is already inheritted in the namespace, 
    # and 100 is the fallback value
```

For the code you provide, I understand you kind of get the functioning of nested functions, but you fail to grasp the idea of namespaces. To tell from a namespace, a scope and a function/method argument, I recommend you some reading:

> A scope refers to a region of a program where a namespace can be
>   directly accessed, i.e. without using a namespace prefix. In other
>   words: The scope of a name is the area of a program where this name
>   can be unambiguously used, for example inside of a function. A name's
>   namespace is identical to it's scope. Scopes are defined statically,
>   but they are used dynamically.

https://www.python-course.eu/namespaces.php

You may find this other link useful:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-parameters-and-arguments-in-Python however best is always read Python docs for a precise and complete understanding ;)

Comment: Take a time to read [PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) that will help you understand why your code does not works.

Comment: Well, starting with that the link shows a 404, I don’t know what’s left to see, @MauroBaraldi

Comment: Oops, I confuse the usage of scope with that of argument passing. I thought the position argument 'x' in nested will be assigned the value of x defined in test incorrectly, but there is no such usage for argument which just exists in scope. It comes out to me after understanding your viewpoint, Thank you!!!

Comment: @Leon you're welcome! Consider accepting my anser if it solved your problem ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/246216

Comment: Sorry Rocamonde, I am a rookie, don't know how to operate. Could you tell me how to accept your answer, and I'm glad to!

Comment: Sure. In the link I posted in my previous comment there is an explanation. Short explanation: in an answer, below the score with the up and down arrows (left side) you have a "check" icon if you are the person who asked the question. If you click it, you accept the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `a = test()`, you have called the `test()` function, and got the `nested` function. This function *needs* an argument, so you can't call it by `a()` alone (it's like calling it by `nested()`). You would need to modify this to `def nested()` for your code to work, and, more importantly, to see that the function "remembers" the `x` defined outside.

A more typical example would be

```
def test(x):
    def nested(y):
    print(f'x is {x}, y is {y}')
return nested

a = test(5)
a(12)
```

Comment: Yes, I get your point. Argument binding is not the same thing as scope, I need to recognize them. Thank you blue_note! Is it your nickname?

Comment: @Leon: arguments binding is the `y`, and happens during function call. but `x` is known because if comes from the outer scope, before the function is called. Works as if it was a global variable. Yep, blue_note is just a username.